# Converting list items into lowercase

Tags: python

Quick one: How do I convert list items(words) into smaller cases?

```
states_list = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California']
```

Comment: `[i.lower() for i in states_list ]`

Comment: Please consider searching the archives for "Quick ones".  Most have been answered numerous times. (tip: Google is better for searching Stack Overflow than then SO search bar)

Comment: `map(str.lower, states_list)`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the method .lower() on the items and create a new list using list comprehension.

```py
foo = [i.lower() for i in states_list]
print (foo)
```

which results in a new list of

```
['alabama', 'alaska', 'arizona', 'arkansas', 'california']
```